# How do I start tmux with N equally-sized, vertically-split panes given an arbitrary list of startup directories?

Tags: shell-script, tmux

I want a shell script that will launch `tmux` with `N` equally-sized, vertically-split panes, each with its own starting directory, where `N` is determined by the number of starting directories specified. For example,

```
tmux-launch SESSION-NAME DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 ...
```

It would be very useful to be able to provide an intial command(s) corresponding to each starting directory. For example,

```
tmux-launch SESSION-NAME DIR1:"CMD1" DIR2:"CMD2" DIR3:"CMD3" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script I wrote to do this. Save it as `tmux-launch.sh` (`chmod +x tmux-launch.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    current=$(tmux display -p "#S")
    cat<<EOF

USAGE: $(basename $0) SESSION DIR [DIR] ...

        [DIR]   one or more startup directories; at least one is required

EOF
    if [[ -n $current ]]; then
        echo "current session: $current"
    fi
    exit 1
else
    session="$1"
    shift
fi

# start tmux
tmux new-session -s $session -d

args=( "$@" )

i=1
for e; do

    # capture directory and optional command from $e
    d=$(echo $e | cut -d: -f1)
    c=$(echo $e | cut -d: -f2)

    if [ ! -d $d ]; then
        echo WARNING: directory does not exist, $d >&2
        continue
    fi

    # Select pane $i, set dir to $d, run pwd
    if [ $i -gt 1 ]; then
        tmux split-window
    fi
    tmux select-pane -t $i
    tmux send-keys "cd $d" C-m
    if [ -n "$c" ]; then
        # execute optional command
        tmux send-keys "$c" C-m
    fi

    # equally-spaces
    tmux select-layout even-vertical

    i=$(expr $i + 1)

done

# Finished setup, attach to the tmux session!
tmux attach-session -t $session
```

For example, the following usage will launch a `tmux` session named "work" with five panes, each starting in a unique directory, and execute the `pwd` command in each pane  and `echo tada` command in the first (of course this exmple assumes that the `~/scratch*` directories exist):

```
tmux-launch.sh work ~/scratch1:"pwd;echo tada" \
                    missing-directory:"echo do nothing" \
                    ~/scratch2:pwd ~/scratch3:pwd ~/scratch4:pwd ~/scratch5:pwd
```

This tool will skip any non-existent directory, and print a warning to `stderr`.

I've testing this on Red Hat Enterprise Linux and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server distros using `tmux` versions `2.7`, `3.1c`, `3.2a` and `3.3`.

***EDIT 2024-03-02:*** A more complicated edition of the script described above is found [here](https://gist.github.com/dapimentel/fcc1b19eddb76b52513641b1eb32fa31). This extended script provides some additional options, including horizontal split and tiled layouts.

***EDIT 2024-03-04:*** This script assumes that your `tmux` configuration begins with pane number 1 instead of the default 0. For example, in my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# Set the base-index to 1 rather than 0
set -g base-index 1
set-window-option -g pane-base-index 1
```